# Is there an easy way to turn the string "5 < 6" into true in C++, linux?

Tags: c++, linux, constraints

I'm coding up an algorithm which counts the number of solutions to a system of constraints. The constraints in this case are predicates such as "a < b" or "a = 3+b or a = 6+b", which I will receive as input strings. I need to be able to ask if any given selection of values for the variables is a valid combination, and I would rather not have to build a parser to do it.

Is there a quick C++ library out there that evaluates strings as mathematical expressions? I think I have a simple way of transforming "a < b" into "5 < 6", I just need a way to evaluate that.

Comment: Now you need to parse a string, but you don't want to use a parser?

Comment: To the close-voters - why is this not a real question? O_o

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: He said he didn't want to *build* a parser. I don't read it to mean that he doesn't want to *use* one.

Comment: Oh I don't mind using one that already exists, I just don't want to spend a week or more learning how to use Lex and Yacc.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  Do you just need to evaluate mathematical expressions or do you need to solve systems of equations?  Is the `=` in `a = 6 + b` intended to mean assignment or is this intended to be an equation?

Comment: @James McNellis: It is an equation. All the variables are integers with finite domains.

Comment: @Thomas: That changes the problem considerably. Compared to solving systems of equations, expression evaluation is Easy-with-a-capital-E. Are they all linear equations? Is there an upper limit on the number of variables you need to solve for? I'd recommend modifying your question to clearly state that you don't just need to evaluate expressions; you need to solve systems of equations.

Comment: @James: No, I'm not solving a system of equations. What I'm doing is trying to sample uniformly over the solution space of a constraint satisfaction problem. The constraints I am working with are represented by equations which I get in the form of strings. The algorithm I use to sample first has to count the number of solutions for various partial assignments to the set of variables. The part I haven't done yet is checking if a given assignment of variables satisfies the constraint I am currently looking at, by plugging the values into one of the equations.

Answer (score 4):

Writing a simple arithmetic expression parser was an exercise at school. It's really not that complicated. Give it a try!

The idea was to convert it to [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and then it becomes dead easy to evaluate it. The above Wikipedia article has all the details you need.

Also the tools "Flex" and "Bison" come to mind, although I haven't used them myself.

Comment: If you're going to go through the pain of conversion to RPN you might as well just evaluate it and skip the RPN conversion step

Comment: Its real simple to hack a simple limited one together. TO build a real one is actually rather complex.

Comment: @Martin York - do you wish to say that the RPN method (that we did in school) is incomplete? I think that with maybe a few additions (like variables) it can pretty much parse any such [valid] expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this in C or C++

You will need to build your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a library that does that for you, but I would do it myself, given how simple it is (it seems so on the surface at least).
And validating it would be very easy and ideal for a regular expression -- you just omit the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could download a relatively small interpreted language, like Lua, and use their existing code. For trivial ops like this it's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tank to kill a fly approach.. :)

[boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html).

It's pretty trivial to define parsers for what you are trying to do, and they have some examples which are what you are looking for. May save you digging around bison, lex and yacc..

Answer (score 0):

Embed perl http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html it is fast and does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This [C++ implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/rpnexpressionevaluator.aspx) might be what you want.